# "Least trivial" function preserving rationality

Tags: functions, soft-question, rational-numbers

Is there a "non-trivial" function $f(x,y)$ such that

$$f(x,y) \in \mathbb{Q} \iff x,y\in \mathbb{Q}?$$

An example of a "trivial" function would be

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0 & x,y\in \mathbb{Q}\\ \pi & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$ 
or any other $f$ which effectively uses a cases function.

The motivation is just my curiosity. Obviously, operations which preserve one direction of the $\iff$ are plentiful and well-studied. I was wondering how onerous the condition of the additional direction is on the choice of $f$. [This question on mathoverflow seems related.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21003/polynomial-bijection-from-mathbb-q-times-mathbb-q-to-mathbb-q)

Comment: Well, you definitely can't have a continuous function satisfy this. If any two values of $f$ differ, you can come up with uncountably many paths between them (e.g. $(x,Cx(1-x))$ parameterizes in $C$ such a family of paths from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$) and then choose some rational $r$ between their values, and the intermediate value theorem says that $f(x,y)=r$ has uncountably many solutions - but $\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q$ is countable, so that's not good. More strongly, $f$ may not be continuous on any open set.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Perhaps a slightly less trivial example would be the function $f$ that interleaves the decimal digits of $x$ and $y$: that is, if
\begin{align}
x&=0.x_1x_2x_3\dots \\
y&=0.y_1y_2y_3\dots
\end{align}
are decimal expansions of $x$ and $y$, then
$$
f(x,y)=0.x_1y_1x_2y_2x_3y_3\dots
$$

You can make this definition unambiguous by deciding to always (or never) take finite decimal expansions when they are available.

Then $f(x,y)$ has a repeating decimal expansion if and only if both $x$ and $y$ do, and so it satisfies your condition.

Comment: This is a really good answer. One might be tempted to use arithmetic operations for this but the irrationals are not closed under the standard arithmetic operations so that approach isn't very fruitful. Very nice insight!

Comment: Similarly, interleaving the continued fraction expansions of $x$ and $y$ preserves rationality, since a real number is rational if and only if its continued fraction terminates.

Comment: This is even continuous at points where neither $x$ nor $y$ has a terminating decimal!

Comment: Does it follow then that this function is almost everywhere continuous?

Comment: These are both nice. It seems that any representation that distinguishes rationals from irrationals could be used.

Comment: @Hugh: Yes, this follows from Meelo's comment. The set of discontinuities is a subset of $(\mathbb Q \times \mathbb R) \cup (\mathbb R \times \mathbb Q)$, which has measure zero.

Comment: On the other hand, the set of discontinuities is uncountable, dense and connected, while its complement is not connected.

Comment: The usual problem with this interlace scheme (that it is not onto) is not a problem here, because that is not required in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question.

The answer would depend
on how the functions are defined.
My inclination is to say
that the answer is "no",
because irrationals can be made to
cancel out
to give a rational.

However,
if limiting processes can be used,
perhaps a function that
uses the fact that
rationals can not be well-approximated
by rationals
(error in approximation by $a/b$ at best $\Omega(1/b)$)
and irrationals can
(error in approximation by $a/b$ at worst $O(1/b^2)$)
could be constructed.

Comment: Of course, limiting processes can result in cases functions like that in the OP's example.

Answer (score -1):

I think the function f must be understood to be from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ so I choose

[image]

Comment: This is "trivial".